# CSP issue using AJAX requests on in a Crossrider extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, crossrider

I'm trying to run an AJAX request in a Crossrider extension but I get a CSP related error.

Here's my code (modified for privacy):

```
$.ajax({
  url : "https://example.com/...",
  type : 'POST',
  dataType : 'json',
  data : {user: "user", pass: "pass"}
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log("POST Succeeded");
  }).fail(function(a, b, c, d) {
    console.log("POST Failed");
});
```

If I run the code from the extension it doesn't work and it gives an "Access Denied" error!

Why cannot I run the request in my Crossrider extension?

Answer (score 4):

Using standard jQuery AJAX methods in an extension can often lead to *cross domain* issues that prevent access to the content; hence, when coding Crossrider extensions it's best practice to use the [appAPI.request](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.request) methods provided with the framework that are developed specifically to be *cross browser* and *cross domain* safe.

So in your case, you could rewrite the POST request in your *extension.js* or *background.js*, as follows:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  appAPI.request.post({
    url: "https://example.com/...",
    contentType: "application/json",
    postData: {user: "user", pass: "pass"},
    onSuccess: function(response) {
      console.log("POST Succeeded");
    },
    onFailure: function(code) {
      console.log("POST Failed");
    }
  });
});
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]